# Inventory tool to document customers services and associated network connectivity details?

Tags: networking, documentation

Has anyone a recommendation for an inventory tool to document:

- customers,
- services associated by each customer,
- network connectivity details (IP, TCP, ftp, http): typically local and remote TCP socket details and layer on top.

Comment: Like @user34092 I've always seen this done through some sort of home-made spreadsheet/database/document. In addition to the above, a product for keeping track of the various circuits and/or the remote routers supporting customers seems to be a large gap in the market. I can only assume that big ISPs/telcos build their own systems in house...

Comment: @Murali Suriar  Yes that seems to be a gap. Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always created an Access or Excel-based solution for this.  Everything I've found online has either been too simple, or so complex that configuration requires more time than just building something in 20-30 minutes in Access.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That's exactly my experience: I also have home-cooked MS-Access database. Just checking if there's anything I am missing out on.